# Parallel randomForest with foreach not running anything in parallel in R

Tags: r, windows, parallel-processing, random-forest, parallel-foreach

I'm trying to fit a randomForest in parallel across the 4 cores on my laptop with the foreach package for some data x and response y using the code:

```
    rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(200, 3), .combine=combine, .packages='randomForest', verbose=TRUE) %dopar% {  
  randomForest(x, as.factor(y), ntree=ntree, mtry=6 , keep.forest=TRUE, seed=1, replace=TRUE)
         }
```

However, even when the  cluster is setup as below it does not work, so a randomForest is fitted but with only 200 trees instead of 600.

```
 library(randomForest)
 library(foreach)
 library(doParallel)

 no_cores <- detectCores()  # Number of cores
 cl<-makeCluster(no_cores) #4
 registerDoParallel(cl)
```

I was wondering how to fix this, or if I had to change a setting to allow R access to multiple cores? I have a windows 10 laptop if that helps.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Using `doParallel` will launch N number of R sessions in parallel. You can confirm this in taskmanager you should see 4 Rterm.exe processes with N = 4. Next,  the foreach functions splits the given task, assigns to parallel processes and aggregates the results. Essentially, using parallelization you can reduce the computation time for a given task. This has nothing to do with number of trees (ntree parameter) of randomForest. It will always have the same `ntree` number of trees as per input

Comment: caret can help here http://topepo.github.io/caret/parallel.html

Comment: Oh I see, so its 300 trees but they are spread across 4 cores. Thanks!